# Generalization of vertex transitivity

Tags: graph-theory

I understand vertex transitivity of a graph $G$ as the property that the local environment, i.e., all incident edges and their vertices, of any 2 vertices looks the same.

What if we extend this notion of similarity to k-hop neighborhood of vertices, including the environment up to some distance k? Is there a generalization of this property such that the k-hop environments of any 2 vertices look the same?

Comment: Vertex transitivity already requires that the "k-hop" neighbourhood of all vertices is identical for all $k$.